# how to calculate renderRow in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to calculate renderRow in listView. actually i need to show index of the row with data. its working fine for subitems but not working for parent. i did like this-

```
render() {
    return(
     <ScrollView style={styles.drawer}>
       <View style={styles.content} key={1}>
          <ListView
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={(data) =>                        
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.navMenuTop}>
                                {'› '+data.Name}
                            </Text>

                             {data.SubItems.map((b,Index) =>
                              <View>
                                   <Text style={styles.navMenu} onPress={this.handlePressCatid.bind(this,b.cPath)}> {'» '+b.Name+"=="+Index}</Text>


                                   {b.SubItems != undefined && b.SubItems.map((c) =>         
                                     <View>
                                      <Text style={styles.navMenu} onPress={this.handlePressCatid.bind(this,c.cPath)}> {'»»»» '+c.Name}</Text>
                                     </View>             
                                   )}


                               </View> 
                                )}
                        </View>
                        }
           />

        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to show Index with data.Name . its working properly for b.Name and c.Name. how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use `rowId` for your purpose `(rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) => renderable` please see, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html
and maybe look at this example too: https://medium.com/differential/react-native-basics-how-to-use-the-listview-component-a0ec44cf1fe8
Hope this helps.

Comment: @Ranjeet sing, rowId should be third parameter. Then only you will get correct ID. If You use as a second parameter then you will get s1

Answer (score 0):

Ranjeet,

You can visit https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#renderrow

in your case,
In renderRow callback you receive 4 parameters (rowData, sectionID, rowID) 
  so just pass rowID to your UI function like this way

```
_renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID){  
    //use this rowID to show  Index with data.Name
    return <View>
      <Text style={styles.navMenuTop}>
        {'› ' + rowData.Name}
      </Text>

      {rowData.SubItems.map((b, Index) =>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.navMenu} onPress={this.handlePressCatid.bind(this, b.cPath)}> {'» ' + b.Name + "==" + Index}</Text>
          {b.SubItems != undefined && b.SubItems.map((c) =>
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.navMenu} onPress={this.handlePressCatid.bind(this, c.cPath)}> {'»»»» ' + c.Name}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  }



render() {
    parentIndex = 0;
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.drawer}>
        <View style={styles.content} key={1}>
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID) => this._renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID)}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this like:

```
render() {
    return(
     <ScrollView style={styles.drawer}>
       <View style={styles.content} key={1}>
          <ListView
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                     renderRow={((data,sectionID:number,rowID:number) =>                        
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.navMenuTop}>
                                {'› '+data.Name+rowID}
                            </Text>

                             {data.SubItems.map((b,Index) =>
                              <View>
                                   <Text style={styles.navMenu} onPress={this.handlePressCatid.bind(this,b.cPath)}> {'» '+b.Name+"=="+Index}</Text>


                                   {b.SubItems != undefined && b.SubItems.map((c) =>         
                                     <View>
                                      <Text style={styles.navMenu} onPress={this.handlePressCatid.bind(this,c.cPath)}> {'»»»» '+c.Name}</Text>
                                     </View>             
                                   )}


                               </View> 
                                )}
                        </View>
                        }
           />

        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```